# How to fix this program to show 0's in the output

Tags: c

I have this code

```
int main()
    {
        int mobBroj,prvicifri,vtoricifri,treticifri;
        scanf("%d", &mobBroj);
        prvicifri = mobBroj / 1000000;
        vtoricifri = (mobBroj % 1000000) / 1000;
        treticifri = mobBroj % 1000;
        if(prvicifri == 70 || prvicifri == 72 || prvicifri == 71)
        printf("0%d/%d-%d T-mobile", prvicifri, vtoricifri, treticifri);
        else if(prvicifri == 75 || prvicifri == 76 || prvicifri == 77 || prvicifri == 78)
        printf("0%d/%d-%d A1", prvicifri, vtoricifri, treticifri);
        else
        printf("0%d/%d-%d LycaMobile", prvicifri, vtoricifri, treticifri);
    
        return 0;
    }
```

And for input 070120004 i get 070/120-4. If the zero is at the beggining its not outputing. How to fix this?

Comment: `"%03d"` prints leading `0` if the number has less than 3 digits. Usually phone numbers are not numbers, they are strings, because leading zeros are important.

Comment: Yea i know but i had to do it this way. But %03d helped. Thanks :)

Comment: The `int` type has no way to distinguish between 4, 04, 004, 00004 as those are the same number. If you know how many digits there should be, you can use a format with leading zeroes as suggested above, if you don't know and want to preserve the number of zeroes from the input, use strings.